# Uplaod wordpress to godaddy and Error Link (menu redirects to localhost)

Tags: wordpress

Now I have some problems that need all of you to help me.
I have installed wordpress to my local computer. After i create site completely, I upload it to my domain name in [godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com).
When i click to menu, it goes to localhost, why?
my site is [bestmart.vishalmart.com](http://bestmart.vishalmart.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Because in wordpress all the paths are hardcoded in the rows of every table of the database.

So before migrating your database in production environment you need to change all the occurrencies of the domain from localhost to your domain name.

If you try to do it by hand it's going to be a hell.

Instead an easy solution could be achieved using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

Answer (score 0):

Paths are found the database. They way i do it, is to export the database from localhost, open it with Notepad++, and Find and replace all the links, from local path to web server address

> change from http:://localhost/mysite to http:://www.mysite.com

Comment: This is mainly ok, but in case you are using some particular plugin/theme the take advantage of the usage of the storage of dynamic fields options, this trick could not work. I experienced that several times before dropping this as an option. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You still need to edit the database.
Go to database > find the `wp-option` > change the `url` option to bestmart.vishalmart.com

or install this plugin on your localhost
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/
This plugin is the simpliest plugin that change all links from old(localhost) to new (your domain). Just read its documentation.